# How to implement ads with viewpager between fragments?

Tags: android

I have been looking for this answer a while, and i haven't found any good solution which would help me getting started in creating this. This is what i would like to do. Like we have view types in lists and we can show different layouts on different position in lists using those view types, i would like to do that also with viewpager. I'm showing some images from server in viewpager, so user can swipe them, but i would like to show user between those images on every 5 image ad. How can i accomplish that?

This is how my viewpager adapter looks:

```
private class JokesImagesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public JokesImagesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        JokePageFragment fragment = new JokePageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(jokes.get(position).toBundle());
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jokes.size();
    }
}
```

And i guess that probably i need to create one more fragment and call it here with implementation of ads.

Comment: did you find any solution for displaying native ad?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of ads you want to show in your app - Interstitial or Native ad?

If you want to just show an interstitial ad on every 5 swipes - just attach an OnPageChangeListener to your ViewPager and count the swipes.

If you want to show a native ad, you have to create a new fragment (as you thought) which will be showing the ad. You have to count and return the ad fragment in the getItem() method of your adapter. Another way to handle this is to use one fragment which will be notified whether to show or not an ad view or a normal view.

Comment: Well, first i will go with native ad, but if i can't make it, i will go with Interestitial. Problem is how to return exact count with regular fragments?

Comment: I want to show native ad and I added one for fragmnet on evry 5th position but it's not working well?

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is that you should modify your jokes model a little, which could accept objects instead of just images(and your custom parameters) and then cast the object to the required datatype and then while populating jokes, you should add  the ad object every 5th position, that would do the work.

Comment: did you find any solution for displaying native ad?